# The magic in Once Upon a Time

Tags: magic, once-upon-a-time

In The Once Upon a Time universe is there a limit to what magic can do ? And what abilities have been displayed?

Comment: Interesting questions; but you should separate them into different posts. "**What's the limit?**" And "**what's been shown?**" Are different enough to create two questions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  And No.

We have seen a number of supposed limits on magic in the Once Upon A Time universe.  E.g. as just one example, we know that certain poisons (e.g. Dreamshade) do not appear to be curable by magic or else Rumplestiltskin would have cured himself after being stabbed by Hook.

[Wiki Dreamshade](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/Dreamshade)

More importantly, we know as is often stated, "All magic comes with a price, Dearie." That would imply that within the Once Upon a Time Universe even if certain magic was technically "possible" the price would be so high in terms of what would have to be sacrificed it would not be able to be performed. In that sense, the phrase might be considered a "Law of Magic" just as we have "Laws of Nature."  If so, from that, we might reasonably deduce that anything that has a constraining "Law" by definition has something that it cannot do. I.e. that certain limits would have to apply.

Or, put another way, the overriding limit to Magic in the show is that it cannot ever be performed without a price of some kind. This would actually be consistent with our universes' laws of thermodynamics and entropic decay. What the price is and how it affects one cannot always be known, but it has to be there just as one cannot reverse entropy.

This would also be consistent with what we know of other magical universes such as Harry Potter. E.g. in that world there are the Five Principal Exceptions to Gamp's Law of Elemental Transfiguration

[Harry Potter Magic Limits](http://www.beyondhogwarts.com/harry-potter/articles/the-five-principal-exceptions-to-gamps-law.html)

**That said, however,** what all the limits are for the Once Upon a Time universe and under what conditions they apply we do not know. Nor, will the writers probably let it deter them from a way to get around any law that does happen to be stated. More on this can be found at the following site in which we see even the stated "Three Restrictions on Magic" have been broken within the show.

That is as much a problem in the "real world" dramas in which the "Laws of Physics" routinely happen to be broken. :-)  The includes breaking the laws of gravity, thermodynamics, etc., etc., etc.   LOL

[Wikia Once Upon a Time - Magic](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/Magic)

Comment: Pretty sure the phrase "Laws of Magic" has come up more than once in dialogue, quite sure spoken at least once by Regina.

Comment: All magic comes with a price. To obtain, something of equal value must be lost. In those days, we really believed that to be the world's one, and only truth.